# Properties inside an ArrayList inside a HashMap always null

Tags: java, hashmap, thymeleaf

I'm trying save form data in a hashmap whose value is an ArrayList of objets (named FilterForm). When I try to submit the form, in the entryKey values of the map are well but some table values from the map are null.

This is the map, first I initialize it:

The map is initialized with the following, before processing the data:

```
private Map<String, List<FilterForm>> filtros = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<FilterForm>>();

public CustomSearchForm() {
        this.filtros.put("datos_personales", new ArrayList<FilterForm>());
        this.filtros.put("datos_institucion", new ArrayList<FilterForm>());

}
```

Then catch the values with this thymeleaf form

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <select th:id="'accion_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" onchange="cambioCombo(this);" th:if="${ff.tipoCampo != 'Booleano'}" class="form-control select2me" form="customSearch"
        placeholder="Acción"
        th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].accion}">
        <option th:each="a : ${customSearch.ACCIONES}" th:value="${a}"
                th:text="${a}"></option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
    <input th:id="'valueField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" th:if="${ff.tipoCampo == 'Numero' or ff.tipoCampo == 'Texto' or ff.tipoCampo == 'Tabla'}" form="customSearch"
        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor"
        th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].value}" />

  <div th:if="${ff.tipoCampo == 'Fecha'}" th:id="'dateField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" class="date"
        data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <input form="searchForm"
            class="form-control input-lg date" th:id="'valueFieldDate_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}"
            th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].value}" 
            th:name="'valueField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" type="text" placeholder="Fecha" />
    </div>
```

`f` property came when I loop hashmap and `status` variable when loop the list inside that map.